# This strange series : $\sum \frac{\sin(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to demonstrate the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum \frac{\sin(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

I know I can prove the convergence by the comparison test. I started like

$$\frac{\sin(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$

but now I'm stuck because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges. With which sequence can I compare it to be able to use the comparison test?

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Try to use a better bound than $1$ for $\sin (1/n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried $n$. But didn't seem to helps me... What can I use.

Comment: $n$ is larger than $1$. What sort of bounds for $\sin x$ do you know?

Comment: @DanielFischer Now, the only bounds who appear in my head is ${-1; 1}$.

Comment: How does $\sin$ behave near $0$?

Comment: I suppose that any real number greater than $1$ will be a sup. bound of $\sin(1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(\frac1n)\leq \frac1n$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin(x) < x$
for $0 < x < \pi/2$,

$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\sin(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}}
< \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1/n}{\sqrt{n}}
 \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$

and this converges by lots of tests.